# ERRO: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, syntax-error

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um site de compra de um jogo que possui uma página para registrar as informações de cada compra, entre elas, a quantidade de jogos comprados.

Eu queria que, durante o salvamento das informações, a quantidade de jogos comprados fosse subtraída do estoque.

**Minha tentativa:**

```
<?php

    $nome               = $_POST['NOME'];
    $cpf                = $_POST['CPF'];
    $email              = $_POST['EMAIL'];
    $quantidade         = $_POST['QUANTIDADE'];
    $pagamento          = $_POST['PAGAMENTO'];


    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'ecoventura') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $jogos = mysqli_query($strcon, "select JOGOS from estoque");
    $novaquan = $jogos - $quantidade; //ESSA É A LINHA DO ERRO

    $sql = "INSERT INTO compra (NOME, CPF, EMAIL, QUANTIDADE, PAGAMENTO) VALUES ('$nome','$cpf', '$email', '$quantidade', '$pagamento')"; 
    $modifica = "UPDATE  `ecoventura`.`estoque` SET `JOGOS` = '$novaquan'";

    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro" . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_query($strcon,$modifica) or die("Erro ao tentar modificar estoque" . mysqli_error($strcon));
    mysqli_close($strcon);
    /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';*/


?>
```

O formulário até salva as informações, mas a coluna jogos tem um registro e aparentemente $jogos contem a quantidade de registros e não o conteúdo dele.

**O erro apresentado é esse:**

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int
>   in C:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\ecoventura\salva-form.php on line 13

Como posso pegar o conteúdo do registro e não sua quantidade?

Comment: O retorno da função `mysqli_query` não é um número, então não faz sentido fazer uma operação algébrica com `$jogos`, como fez. Você selecionou a coluna jogos de todos os registros da tabela estoque, qual seria o resultado esperado para `$jogos - $quantidade`?

Comment: Ah, então é por isso que tá dando -4. Jogos tá recebendo 1 porque só tem um registro. Como eu faço pra pegar o conteúdo desse registro e não a quantidade de registros?

Comment: Errado. Você não está pegando a quantidade, está pegando o conteúdo, só está utilizando o retorno de forma errada. Vide documentação, o retorno da função `mysqli_query` é uma instância de `mysqli_result`, então estude a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) para verificar como trabalhar com esse objeto.

Comment: Então, eu não sei se eu entendi direito mas lendo a documentação parece que aquele mysqli_num_rows ( mysqli_result $result ) : int pega o conteúdo do registro, mas tentei usar e não funcionou. Por que?

Comment: Também não. Como o próprio nome da função diz, `num rows` retorna a quantidade de registros retornado na consulta. *Returns **number of rows** in the result set*. O que você precisa são as funções *fetch*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na verdade entre as linhas 10 e 11 do teu código.

```
    (linha 10) $jogos = mysqli_query($strcon, "select JOGOS from estoque");
    (linha 11) $novaquan = $jogos - $quantidade; //ESSA É A LINHA DO ERRO
```

Na linha 10, **$jogos** retornará FALSE caso não encontre nenhum dado para a consulta ou um array de objetos, logo o ideal seria primeiro tratar esse resultado para então rodar a função do PHP mysqli_num_rows() para retornar o número de linhas para o resultado da consulta:

```
   if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "select JOGOS from estoque")) {

        /* determine final result */
        $TotalDeJogosEncontrados = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $novaquan = $TotalDeJogosEncontrados - $quantidade;

        /* return a row from result */
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        /* close result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
```

Comment: O retorno não é falso quando não encontra dados, nem array quando encontra. Em ambas as situações o retorno é uma instância de `mysqli_result`. Falso só é retornado em casos de falha durante a execução da SQL.

Comment: Está na documentação do PHP que mysqli_result Returns FALSE em caso de falha, tanto que se não tiver resultado não entra no if. Agora com relação ao retorno, realmente me expressei mal retornará uma instância do mysqli_result.

Comment: Nesse caso não encontrar registros é considerado falha? Não lembro deste detalhe.

Comment: Eu tentei usar seu código e adicionei mais um registro na coluna jogos, que agora possui dois registros. Dei um var_dump() e percebi que o $TotalDeJogosEncontrados tá retornando a quantidade de registros da coluna. Como essa coluna sempre terá somente um registro eu gostaria de pegar o conteúdo dele. Como faço isso?

Comment: Uai para pegar o conteúdo de um mysqli_result, retornar uma linha e tal é só usar o mysql_fetch_assoc.

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$JogoData = $row["JOGOS"];